# error with getting all users in role

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, roles, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to get a list of all users in a role, and despite the numerous questions and links I've read on here, I can't seem to figure this Identity stuff out. Below is what I'm currently working with:

```
IdentityRole role = context.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == rolesDDL.SelectedValue).First();
var users = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));
```

However this gets an error that says "Sequence contains no elements" on the role line. I tried doing a similar bit of code with the UserManager/RoleManager but that had the same result:

```
var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var roleManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();

IdentityRole role = roleManager.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == rolesDDL.SelectedValue).First();
var users = userManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));
```

EDIT: It seems to be an issue with the RoleManager not being able to actually find my roles. If I go into ServerExplorer I can see the roles in my AspNetRoles table but after instantiating my RoleManager from the OWIN context it doesn't seem to have any roles still. Could this be an issue from installing RavenDB for the data? I saw how to migrate users to Raven also but I was hoping to get it working with defaults first, before I made more issues for myself.

This is what I currently have in this function:

```
var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var roleManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();

//IdentityRole role = roleManager.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == rolesDDL.SelectedValue).First();
//var users = userManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role. 

//IdentityRole role = context.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == rolesDDL.SelectedValue).First();
//var users = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));

var users = roleManager.FindByName(rolesDDL.SelectedItem.Text).Users;
```

EDIT: Adding initializers per request, found in startup.auth.cs:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Comment: You have a pretty good error there.  Go debug it.  I guess the error could be either the context.Roles has no elements or the rolesDDL.SelectedValue has no elements.  Check them both and then you'll know your next step or can ask another question.

Comment: I started writing this on Friday and finished it this am. whoops. RolesDDL populates with the roles, so I know they exist in the db. I used the same context to grab roles there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your `roleManager` instead and filter it with the role name rather than the role id you can use the following:

```
var roleManager = HttpContext.Current
        .GetOwinContext()
        .Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();

var roleName = rolesDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
var users = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users
```

Comment: It looks like my RoleManager isn't setup right or something? I know the roles are in the db, because they load into the rolesDDL, but rolemanager has a count of 0 when I try using it. Isn't that supposed to be setup out of the box?

Comment: Did you try using RoleManager yet?

Comment: @JordanWayneCrabb Sorry I'm not at a PC to try the code. Will take a look when I'm back on, unless you get an answer first.

Comment: @AdamHeeg see my edit. hutchonoid: thanks, I'm going to continue playing with it, but I feel like I'm shooting in the dark at this point.

Comment: I've used role manager and aspnet roles, but not the way you are with Raven and OWIN.  sorry I can't help.

Comment: @JordanWayneCrabb I've added the way I return a rolemanager to my answer. :)

Comment: I tried that your line and mine above, leading me to think it's definitely an issue with the manager actually finding the roles. Maybe I'm missing a line somewhere else?

Comment: @JordanWayneCrabb How are you initializing your usermanager and stores? Can you include the code or is that missing?

Comment: @hutchonoid just getting back to this project, I included where they're created in the owin context in startup.auth.cs. Are you trying to see those lines or the functions those call?